# rails　seedファイルからdbに画像を保存した画像を表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

rails　画像を表示させたい
環境：　ver.6 "development"

一覧表示機能を実装中に以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

railsで画像を表示させる記述をしたのですが上手く表示されません。

該当のソースコード

```
<% @alcohols.each do |alcohol| %>
    <%= image_tag '/assets/alcohol.images',size: '320x240' %>
```

画像は `app/assets/images` に入れてあります。
imageのカラムの型はstringにしています。

以下の記述にて、seedファイルからdbに画像を保存しました。何も画像に関するGemは使用していません。

```
image:File.open('./app/assets/images/beer-1.png')
```

dbのimageカラムには、`#<File:0x00007fcf62ddf750>`の形で保存されています。

#### 試したこと

bining.pryにてデータが取得できているか確認。
alcohol.image　で `#<File:0x00007fcf62ddf750>` のデータを取得できている。

image_tagの記述を

```
<%= image_tag alcohol.image %>
```

と記述すると

> Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound
> The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.

のエラーが出た為、

```
<%= image_tag '/assets/alcohol.images',size: '320x240' %>
```

と記述することでエラーメッセージは出なくなったのですが、ブラウザで確認すると山の割れた画像が表示されてしまいます。

原因が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。
説明不足な点がございましたら、ご指摘ください。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/326490) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。次回質問より、他サイトでも投稿した際はそのように明示させていただきます。
今回の質問に関しまして、ActiveStorageを用いることで解決できました。
また、質問させていただく際はよろしくお願いいたします。